# I am getting error while using gson.toJson(Object src) : declares multiple JSON fields named ntMgr

Tags: java, json, gson

I searched for solution for my problem before posting but didn't got much.
Problem is I am populating my JsonObject with two product details as below :

```
JSONArray result=new JSONArray();
JSONObject prodListFinal = new JSONObject();
List<JLCRCQProduct> productList = getFromFunction();
  for(JLCRCQProduct product : productList){
   JSONObject prodList = new JSONObject();
   prodList.put("localReference", product.getLocalReference());
   prodList.put("productName", product.getProductName());
   result.put(prodList);
  } 
prodListFinal.put("product", result);
```

When I am trying to create a `buildAjaxResponse` I am passing `prodListFinal` `JsonObject`. But I am getting error at

```
gson.toJson(prodListFinal)
```

Error :

```
ActionController ActionController::doPost()::exception:: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.apache.jackrabbit.core.nodetype.NodeTypeImpl declares multiple JSON fields named ntMgr
```

Note: When I pass only one product detail (I put break in for loop so loop run once) , i am getting my response. But for two product list it's failing.
Could anyone help on this ?

Comment: you already have a jsonObject instance, try prodListFinal.toString();

Answer (score 0):

I think here you have mixed two implementation of JSON (json.org and gson).

You have to change your implementation to use only single implementation.

E.g. (using only gson):

```
JsonArray result=new JsonArray();
JsonObject prodListFinal = new JsonObject();
List<JLCRCQProduct> productList = getFromFunction();
  for(JLCRCQProduct product : productList){
   JsonObject prodList = new JsonObject();
   prodList.addProperty("localReference", product.getLocalReference());
   prodList.addProperty("productName", product.getProductName());
   result.add(prodList);
  } 
prodListFinal.add("product", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sachin for your response.
I figured out the issue which was in my JSON. I was getting JSON like

```
"ImageResource": "ImageResource, type=nt:unstructured, path=/etc/commerce/products/productnumber/images/image, resource=[JcrNodeResource, type=nt:unstructured, superType=null, path=/etc/commerce/products/productnumber/images/image]"
```

Correct JSON should have
`"ImageResource": "/etc/commerce/products/productnumber/images/image"` (Just the path of image)